# Read SSL Certs with user process

Tags: tls, certificates, linux, permissions

I am running my own server, on which I have different services (Nginx etc.).
All these (internet) services are / should be secured with SSL (offcialy signed).

The key files / certificates are located in the directory /etc/ssl.
Nginx (because it has root permissions) can read these files / directory, but other services (which run in the userspace, such as IRCD-Hybrid or ZNC) can not.

How can I secure my key and certs, but at the same time allow these processes to read (not write) them?

Comment: You're worried that "chmod a+r" might go too far?

Comment: I tried, but as a user it still gives me "Permission denied"?
Ownership of the files is `root:root`

Comment: Check that the directories above have "a+x" (not a+r). That lets user reads files they have permission to, but not list the directory contents. However, this may create other security issues. You could also copy the certs to another directory and tweak user apps to look there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you **ever** want users to have access to the servers *private* key. Of course, access to the public key doesn't matter.

I think that your other services should be running under non-privileged but still non-user accounts. Then you can change ownership of the keys to `root:adm` or something more suitable and add the service accounts to the same group. The public key can be world readable.